# Building an alternate maven local repo

Tags: maven

I am running the following maven command:

```
$ mvn dependency:resolve -X -Dmaven.repo.local=/cygdrive/c/tempRepo
```

and I can see in the output the various dependencies being downloaded. But when when I list out the directory, it's empty.

```
$ ls -a /cygdrive/c/tempRepo/
.  ..
```

So if I've specified an alternate local repository and maven appears to be successfully downloading, where is it putting the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/cygdrive/c/tempRepo/` folder that you passed in is specific to cygwin.

Maven won't use cygwin to interpret that path so it will simply fail to find the folder.

Instead, it will use the default local repo location `C:\Users\yourname\.m2\repository\`

Hope that helps.